# Disable CSRF for specific URLs SPA Spring Gateway WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-security, microservices, csrf, webflux

I have next CSRF code in WebFilterChain:

```
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(getURLsForDisabledCSRF())
```

I would like to turn off the CSRF check on POST methods for several URLs. I have found **NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher**, which allows doing next:

```
        return new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(
HttpMethod.POST, "/services/service1/api/some-post-endpoint1", 
"/services/service1/api/some-post-endpoint2");
```

So overall this code works, but when I'm trying to GET request login page or domain page, I will get 'Invalid CSRF' or 'Expected CSRF cannot be found'. Also after Spa tries to redirect me to index.html there will be 403 on this GET redirect the request, which says: Invalid CSRF or no CSRF presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the `requireCsrfProtectionMatcher` you override the default configuration which allows `GET` requests.

If you want to use both, you can return an `AndServerWebExchangeMatcher` from `getURLsForDisabledCSRF` that combines the default CSRF matcher and you custom matcher.

```java
new AndServerWebExchangeMatcher(
    CsrfWebFilter.DEFAULT_CSRF_MATCHER,
    new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
        "/services/service1/api/some-post-endpoint1",
        "/services/service1/api/some-post-endpoint2"))
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! There was no information about that... How did you know that? :)

Comment: In the `requireCsrfProtectionMatcher` Javadoc it states "Configures the ServerWebExchangeMatcher used to determine when CSRF protection is enabled. Default is PUT, POST, DELETE requests."